# Can I ask questions about marketing purposes?

Tags: discussion

I have written open-source software but it's hard to gain any traction, so I'm looking for advice.

Can I post a question regarding this topic when the question includes links to repos / websites etc?

On most online-forums there's a strict anti advertising rule even if it's open source. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

A question about marketing a specific website would be closed as off-topic with the reason:

> Questions that are **specific to one website** are discouraged because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting. See the [How to Ask](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help improving this question.

When you ask a question about marketing a website it must be general enough that it could apply to many other websites with similar situations.  To demonstrate that your question isn't too specific to just your site, you can use `example.com` rather than your actual domain and use a fake name for your software like "Fun Util 2.0" rather than the actual name of your product.

Actual product names and real links aren't prohibited though.  They can be used if it is difficult to explain without a concrete example. Our users often ask for the actual website so they can check the real thing.  It is fine to provide it if asked for it.

When you provide a link to your site or name your product you must make your association with it clear.  You must use phrases like "my site is" or "I'm the developer of."  You also can't mention your site or products in too many of your posts here.  See the "Avoid overt self-promotion" section of [expected behavior in our help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Keep in mind that our site is for questions about websites.  Questions about marketing a website are on-topic, but other aspects of marketing software such as app-store optimization or repository promotion would be off-topic.